# URL sent to Django using AJAX is different when printed from Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a JQuery event that, when a link is clicked, an AJAX POST request is sent to a Django function. There I print the recieved url and do other stuff with it. However, when it is printed (by Django) some characters in the url are changed.

The specific url this happened with was :

```
https://www.catholicleague.org/05press_releases/quarter%204/051110_put_on_notice.htm
```

Which was printed as :

```
https://www.catholicleague.org/05press_releases/quarter+4/051110_put_on_notice.htm
```

Where `%20` was changed to `+`

Here is the AJAX and Django code:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(e.target.href){
            let clicked_source = e.target.href; 
            let csrf_tok = parent.document.getElementById("csrf_tok").value; 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "/change_origin/", 
                data: JSON.stringify({"clicked_source":clicked_source}), 
                type: "POST", 
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_tok );}, 
                success: function(response) { 
                    console.log(response.msg)
                }, 
                error:function(error) { console.log(error); } 
            }); 
    } 
});
```

```
def change_origin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received = ast.literal_eval(request.body.decode())
        print(received)
        clicked_source_url = received['clicked_source']

        return JsonResponse({'msg': "ok"})
```

Where decode is used as the JSON object is received in Python as a byte-like object. And ast is used to turn the string representation of the object to an actual object (or dict) for access.

I need either:

1) A way to just send a string from Ajax to Django

2) A better way to deal with the received object as I believe using `.decode()` might be the one causing this issue.

EDIT: The link is the second link in the "origin" part of this article

```
https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/an-unmerried-woman/
```

Comment: That is not being caused by any of the code you have posted here. Nevertheless, what you are doing is very strange; why are you converting the parameter to JSON in the JS? Then having done so, why are you calling `ast.literal_eval` rather than `json.loads` in the Python?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Where and how? Just copy and paste the code above and edit it. This is my first time using Django so I am not very familiar with it (I mainly learned using NodeJS)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Also, what do you think might be causing this problem then?

Comment: Literally, use `json.loads()` instead of `ast.literal_eval`. But that won't solve your problem, because your problem is not caused by any of the code you have posted here.

Comment: Note that you haven't explained how that JS is being run against the article on Snopes; your problem is probably there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so ```received = json.loads(request.body)``` and I can access the "clicked_source" the same way?

Comment: @DanielRoseman pre-storing the html then displaying the html in an iframe using "srcdoc = {{html}}" where {{html}} is sent from Django (using render)

Comment: So there are at least three complex steps there, any one of which could have caused the issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It worked fine before (and still works with other links), so I dont believe it's html related. I might try and console.log() the url before sending it in AJAX to see if it is changed in the Javascript or later. Ill also start using json.loads. If that fixes it please write your comment in an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added console.log and started using json.loads. Console.log prints the link with ```%204``` while the print in Django shows ```{'clicked_source': '.......+4....'}```. So something happens in-between that causes this change. Any idea what?